# laravel extracting uploaded file fails

Tags: php, laravel

According to [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/requests#retrieving-uploaded-files), it seems the following file extraction should work:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', function (Request $request) {
    if ($request->hasFile('source'    )) { return ">> GOOD ! <<"; }
    if ($request->hasFile('input.json')) { return ">> GOOD ! <<"; }

    $x = count($_FILES);

    return "DD >> $x << DD";
});
```

This is similar (but not identical<sup>1</sup>) to [this post](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/requests#retrieving-uploaded-files):

```
$ curl.exe -X GET -F "source=@input.json" http://127.0.0.1:8008/
DD >> 0 << DD
```

**EDIT**:
When I change the receiving code to `Route::post(...)` then I get:

```
$ curl.exe -X POST -F "source=@input.json" http://127.0.0.1:8008/
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Page Expired</title>
< ... omitted ... >
```

---

<sup>1</sup> In my case `$_FILES` is *also* empty

Comment: `$request->hasFile('source')` here source should be the name of the `input type="file" name="source"`field of your form

Comment: @krisgjika I don't have an explicit form - so I thought that specifying `source` in the http request should fit

Comment: than what do you have? just noticed this is a get route. If you want to pass files and other post data, make a post request to a post route

Comment: I have a micro service with a single endpoint running php code. Regarding the GET/POST point - when I change request type I get a long html response that doesn't make sense. I'll edit my question to add the details

Comment: A GET request can't have a file. And a 419 CSRF error is well-covered ground